# Solving $xf^{\prime\prime}= 4f^{\prime}- 25x^9 f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone explain to me how to solve the following differential equation,
$$xf^{\prime\prime}= 4f^{\prime}- 25x^9 f \qquad  \text{with initial conditions}   \ f(0)=0, \ \ f^{'}(1)=1 $$
There is a hint which asks me to make the substitution, $t=x^5$. I really am a total novice in differential equations and my only attempt has been to write the function as a power series and try to guess the coefficients. It doesn't seem very inspiring though.

Comment: Are those really $f$ and one is not $f'$?

Comment: Do you mean to have $4f'$?

Comment: So sorry for the typo, its fixed now.

Comment: I think the substitution you want is $x^5=t$, not $x=t^5$.

Comment: *Mathematica* yields:  $f(x) = \frac{1}{5} \sec (1) \sin \left(x^5\right)$.

Comment: Yes, thanks @BarryCipra, can someone suggest a method for solving this differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute in the equation
$$f'_x=\frac {df}{dx}=\frac {df}{dt}\frac {dt}{dx}=5x^4\frac {df}{dt}$$
$$f''_x=\frac {d^2f}{dx^2}=\frac {df}{dt}\frac {d^2t}{dx^2}+\frac {d^2f}{dt^2}(\frac {dt}{dx})^2$$
$$f''_x=\frac {20}{x^2} tf'_t+\frac {25}{x^2}t^2f''_t$$
Then the original equation becomes :
$$f''_t+f_t=0$$
$$\implies r^2+1=0 \implies r=i,-i$$
$$f(t)=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)$$
Substitute back $t=x^5$
$$f(x)=c_1\cos(x^5)+c_2\sin(x^5)$$
Apply initial conditions to get $c_1,c_2$

$$f(0)=0 \implies c_1=0 \implies f(x)=c_2\sin(x^5)$$
$$f'(x)=5c_2x^4\cos(x^5) $$
$$f'(1)=1 \implies 1=5c_2\cos(1) \implies c_2=\frac 15 \sec(1)$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac 15 \sec(1)\sin(x^5)}$$